# Firestore cloud function asynchronous execution with promise

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular5

I have orders collection and products collection in my application. The user can have multiple products in their single order. What I want to do is calculating the amount of each product reading through products collection and then perform the further action. Below is what I got as of now.

```
exports.myfunc = functions.firestore.document('collection/{collid}')
    .onCreate(event => {
        let data = event.data.data();
        const products = data.products;
        const prices = [];
        _.each(products, (data1, index) => {
            const weight = data1.weight;
            const isLess = data1.isLess;
            firebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('collection').doc(data1.productId).onSnapshot(data2 => {
                let amount = weight === '1/2' ? data2.data().price1 : data2.data().price1 * weight;
                amount += isLess ? 50 : 0;
                prices.push(amount);
            });
        });
        //Do some task after _.each with new total

});
```

But am not able to achieve synchronous task here, so that I can store actual amount for the product against its order and calculate total to store in document.

Could anyone please tell me how I achieve the above-said scenarios? How I can work along with `promise` and then `callback`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the products array to promises, like this:

```
var productPromises = products.map(product => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebaseOperation()...onSnapshot(resolve)
    })
})
Promise.all(productPromises).then(results => {
    // process all results at once
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use [onSnapshot()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.10.x/DocumentReference#onSnapshot) with Cloud Functions.  That attaches a listener that stay listening indefinitely, until you remove it.  That's not what you want at all, because functions can't execute indefinitely.

Instead, use [get()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.10.x/DocumentReference#get), which returns a promise when the fetch is complete.

Also, you could consider accumulating all the documents you want to access into an array and use [getAll()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.10.x/Firestore#getAll) (with the spread operator on the array) to fetch them all.